# "Cannot find symbol - variable" but... it exist

Tags: java, variables, bluej

I'm new to Java. My homework is to write a CinemaBookingSystem program. This is my main class:

```
public class CinemaBookingSystem
{
    private String CinemaName;
    private Screening screening1;  
    private Screening screening2;   
    private Screening screening3;   
    private Screening screening4; 
    private Screening screening5;   
    private Screening screening6;   
    private Screening screening7;   
    private Screening screening8;   

    /**
     *
     */
    public CinemaBookingSystem()
    {
        Movie movie1 = new Movie("Nemo", 12);
        Movie movie2 = new Movie("Toy's Story", 11);
        Movie movie3 = new Movie("Mulan", 11);
        Movie movie4 = new Movie("Spirited Away", 10);
        Movie movie5 = new Movie("Pocahontas", 11);
        Movie movie6 = new Movie("Garfield", 10);
        Movie movie7 = new Movie("Lord of the Rings", 9);
        Movie movie8 = new Movie("Cloud Atlas", 8);

        Date date1 = new Date("Monday", 16.30);
        Date date2 = new Date("Tuesday", 12.30);
        Date date3 = new Date("Monday", 15.30);
        Date date4 = new Date("Tuesday", 18.00);

        Hall hall1 = new Hall(20, 40);
        Hall hall2 = new Hall(30, 50);
        Hall hall3 = new Hall(40, 50);
        Hall hall4 = new Hall(50, 60);

        Screening screening1 = new Screening(movie1, date1, hall1);
        this.screening1 = screening1;
        Screening screening2 = new Screening(movie2, date2, hall1);
        this.screening2 = screening2;
        Screening screening3 = new Screening(movie3, date3, hall2);
        this.screening3 = screening3;
        Screening screening4 = new Screening(movie4, date4, hall2);
        this.screening4 = screening4;
        Screening screening5 = new Screening(movie5, date1, hall3);
        this.screening5 = screening5;
        Screening screening6 = new Screening(movie6, date2, hall3);
        this.screening6 = screening6;
        Screening screening7 = new Screening(movie7, date3, hall4);
        this.screening7 = screening7;
        Screening screening8 = new Screening(movie8, date4, hall4);
        this.screening8 = screening8;

    }


    public void reserve(Screening screening, int row, int seat)
    {
        if(screening.returnSeatsMap()[row][seat].getSeatsState()==true)
            screening.returnSeatsMap()[row][seat].reserveSeat();
        else
            System.out.print("This seat isn't available.");
    }
```

But the reserve method doesn't work... When I invoke it, it shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6uK6.png

But I created screening1, it is in fields and constructor... Obviously it doesn't work this way and I can accept it, but since yesterday no other solution came to my mind... Any hints?

Btw, sorry for all grammatic mistakes, I'm not native English speaker. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**: ok I didn't think the problem are other classes.
Here is the class Screening:

```
public class Screening
{
    private Movie movie;
    private Date date;
    private Seat[][] seatsMap;
    private Hall hall;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Screening(Movie movie, Date date, Hall hall)
    {
        this.movie = movie;
        this.date = date;
        seatsMap = new Seat[hall.getRows()][hall.getSeats()];
    }

    public Seat[][] returnSeatsMap()
    {
        return seatsMap;
    }


}
```

And here Hall:

```
 public class Hall
{
    private ArrayList<Screening> screenings;
    private int rows;
    private int seats;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Hall(int rows, int seats)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    public int getRows()
    {
        return rows;
    }

    public int getSeats()
    {
        return seats;
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code which tries to call that method - and that's where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question and added two more classes.

Comment: You still don't have where reserve() is actually called - where you have .reserve(.....)

Comment: As I get, that reserve() method is in Seat class.

Comment: Reserve() is placed in the CinemaBooking (main) class... And I call it here: http://i42.tinypic.com/x1f5s0.png  It's that would You mean? I'm using nooby BlueJ and invoke methods manually :)

Comment: @Kalina: Yes - the problem is where you're calling the method, and you still haven't shown the actual code - just a UML diagram...

Comment: Give the main method of your program. Then it's easy to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols (here, the variable `screening1`) should be defined where the `reserve()` method is called. The attributes `private Screening screeningX;` should be located in the class which call `reserve()` (I guess, in a class you didn't post here, cause I don't see any `reserve`call.)

Note for future, use arrays (`Screening[]` or `ArrayList<Screening>` when you have several variables with similar behavior. You will be able to greatly simplify your code.
Good luck =)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Still I'm not sure how to solve it... Look at my comment above. I'm calling the method manually in my program, so there is no class with code which is calling methods... If there is no such class, I don't know where to place attributes `private Screening screeningX` :(

Comment: I guess you call it directly from the `main()` method? It's OK, and it IS in a class. You should then place `private static Screening screeningX` in that class, above the main() method for example. You can also use the screening var locally like any other object : `Screening[] screeningArray = new Screening[8];`